# How to start a resque queue in production (EC2 / Ubuntu)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, rake, resque

Can anybody point me to a solution of how to start run

```
 bundle exec env rake resque:work QUEUE='*'
```

when deploying Rails app in production (I am using EC2 and Ubuntu)? I am not using passenger or any deployment (had to manually set up the server and just copy Rails app manually due to some complications).

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Had to use God for this, the bundle exec route did not happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as with everything rake, this is as simple as `RAILS_ENV=production rake resque:work QUEUE=*`

Comment: If somehow I get disconnected to EC2-ssh-session, will my jobs keep running or will they stop?

Comment: If you start them this way then they're not connected to your session and can disconnect freely

Comment: My jobs run with `rake resque:work QUEUE=*`, but with adding `RAILS_ENV=production`, they don't work.

Comment: Then you've got a problem with your production config - unrelated to this question

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using Ubuntu, using upstart to launch resque workers may work for you. This approach has worked very well for me. Here is a link to a blog post I found when I was setting it up that helped a lot.

http://jasonroelofs.com/2012/03/12/manage-and-monitor-resque-with-upstart-and-monit/

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I do

```
PIDFILE=./resque.pid BACKGROUND=yes QUEUE="*" RAILS_ENV=production  rake resque:work >>  resque.log &
```